# Custom shape of a SeekBar in android application

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I know it is possible to change the style of the SeekBar in android apps, but is it possible to change the shape of the progress line of a SeekBar?

I would like it to be like that:
[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve this? :)

Comment: Hi @tania, did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to this question here [How to make custom seek bar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011144/how-to-make-custom-seek-bar-in-android)

You're not going to be able to do that with the default slider. You're going to have create a custom view. Here's some resources to get you started.

http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Edited to add this other resource the may help you get the curves you want

[Give a semi-circular shape to seekbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424162/give-a-semi-circular-shape-to-seekbar)