# plaese can anyone help me to draw radial seekbar

Tags: android

[Radial SeekBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vsFt.png)

Please help me to how to draw a Radial SeekBar, Plaese check the image url that is actual design of seek bar. I tried many ways but not worked out properly.

I tried like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
tools:context="com.scanner.com.protracterview.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<com.goodiebag.protractorview.ProtractorView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:arcColor="#91d8f7"
    app:arcProgressColor="#91d8f7"
    app:tickColor="#4a4a4a"
    app:indicatorType="line"
    app:tickProgressColor="#abe6"
    app:textColor="#000"
    app:textProgressColor="#FF0000"
    app:angleTextSize="0dp"
    app:arcWidth="2dp"
    app:progressWidth="2dp"
    app:tickOffset="18dp"
    app:tickLength="0dp"
    app:angle="15"
    android:id="@+id/protrat"
    app:tickIntervals="15"
    app:ticksBetweenLabel="three"
    app:touchInside="true"
    app:roundEdges="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/number"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you tried and what "not worked out properly" means. For example, I found [this implementation](https://github.com/GoodieBag/ProtractorView) in about two minutes, searching on [the Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com). Perhaps you could just use it, or learn how they did it to implement your own.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you want something like this -
Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424162/give-a-semi-circular-shape-to-seekbar) - ([Matt Joseph](http://devadvance.com/circularseekbar))

1. There is a class **CircularSeekBar.java** paste it in your project
2. attrs.xml (in res/values/attrs.xml)
3. and your xml file should be like this,

   ```
   <mrbrown.arcseekbar.CircularSeekBar
       android:id="@+id/circularSeekBar1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:start_angle="180"
       app:end_angle="0"
       app:circle_x_radius="500dp"
       app:circle_y_radius="500dp"
       app:use_custom_radii="true"
       app:progress="0"
       app:max="100"
       app:pointer_alpha_ontouch="100"
       app:pointer_color="#0174DF"
       app:pointer_halo_color="#880174DF"/>
   ```

Comment: Thank u for suppport.. i want a line to the bottom